# Mysql Trigger will not pass last_insert_id() to connection

Tags: mysql

This is my schema:

I am trying to have an insert into "desktops" or "laptops" insert an id generated automatically from "computers". That works.

My issue is when I insert into either table, I can not select last_insert_id();

Is there something I am doing wrong? I am trying to pass the id all the way forward to my application, for further processing. Selecting MAX(id) is not a valid solution. My SQL connection makes one insert statement, and the trigger should not break that functionality...

```
Use test;

CREATE TABLE `laptops` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=innodb DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `desktops` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
) ENGINE=innodb DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `computers` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `type` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=innodb DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TRIGGER `laptops_BINS` BEFORE INSERT ON `laptops` FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  IF (EXISTS(SELECT id FROM laptops WHERE name = NEW.name)) THEN
    SET NEW.id = NULL;
  ELSE
    INSERT INTO computers (type) VALUES ('laptop');
    SET NEW.id = LAST_INSERT_ID();
    SET NEW.id = LAST_INSERT_ID(NEW.id);
  END IF;
END

CREATE TRIGGER `desktop_BINS` BEFORE INSERT ON `desktops` FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  IF (EXISTS(SELECT id FROM desktops WHERE name = NEW.name)) THEN
    SET NEW.id = NULL;
  ELSE
    INSERT INTO computers (type) VALUES ('desktop');
    SET NEW.id = LAST_INSERT_ID();
    SET NEW.id = LAST_INSERT_ID(NEW.id);
  END IF;
END

INSERT INTO laptops (name) VALUES ('laptop1');
INSERT INTO laptops (desktop) VALUES ('desktop1');
INSERT INTO laptops (name) VALUES ('laptop2');
INSERT INTO laptops (desktop) VALUES ('desktop2');

SELECT last_insert_id();
```

Expecting 4, actually its 0.

Any thoughts as to how I can fix the trigger? Maybe someone can help me format the AFTER_INSERT statement to fix last_insert_id?

I tried setting the values to auto-increment, and unique in the laptops and desktops table, neither will fix the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than trying to deal with the 'confusion' of 'last_insert_id'. I decided to change the table structure to be a more 'common' format. 
That is change the 'laptops' and 'desktops' tables to have the 'auto_increment' keys. This changes the 'computers' table to have a primary key of 'computer_id' from 'laptops' or 'desktops' and a 'computer_type'.

Here are the table structures and triggers.

It has been tested on mysql 5.5.16 on windows xp.

```
CREATE TABLE `laptops` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `desktops` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=4 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `computers` (
  `computer_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `computer_type` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`computer_id`,`computer_type`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

DELIMITER $$
USE `testmysql`$$
DROP TRIGGER /*!50032 IF EXISTS */ `laptop_bins`$$

CREATE
    /*!50017 DEFINER = 'test'@'localhost' */
    TRIGGER `laptop_bins` AFTER INSERT ON `laptops` 
    FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
      INSERT INTO computers (computer_id, computer_type ) VALUES (new.id, 'laptop');
    END;
$$
DELIMITER ;

DELIMITER $$
USE `testmysql`$$
DROP TRIGGER /*!50032 IF EXISTS */ `desktop_bins`$$

CREATE
    /*!50017 DEFINER = 'test'@'localhost' */
    TRIGGER `desktop_bins` AFTER INSERT ON `desktops` 
    FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
      INSERT INTO computers (computer_id, computer_type ) VALUES (new.id, 'desktop');
    END;
$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Sample Queries and Output:

```
INSERT INTO laptops (NAME) VALUES ('laptop1');
INSERT INTO desktops (NAME) VALUES ('desktop1');
INSERT INTO laptops (NAME) VALUES ('laptop2');
INSERT INTO desktops (NAME) VALUES ('desktop2');

Laptops: 
    id  name     
------  ---------
     1  laptop1  
     2  laptop2  

Desktops:
    id  name      
------  ----------
     1  desktop1  
     2  desktop2  

Computers:
computer_id  computer_type  
-----------  ---------------
          1  desktop        
          1  laptop         
          2  desktop        
          2  laptop
```

Comment: The problem with this structure for my use case is that I am trying to assign each id a property, in an external table. Computer ID, location for instance. So I have tables where the computer_id (and there would be millions of them) should be an integer to reflect which is the actual id. Having them in one table can be solved with a union, saving space in the db.     SELECT id, 'desktop' FROM desktops UNION SELECT id, 'laptop' FROM laptops;  Thanks for the response

Comment: Yes, i did suspect that such as you described may be a possible use case. I still think that trying to manipulate 'last_insert_id' may well end in tears. Would i be correct in thinking that, say, 'laptops.id' is a 'foreign key' to the 'computers.id' table, logically not physically? Same for the 'desktop.id' table?

Comment: Yes, They are foreign keys. In my application, physically (or schematically!). Basically, each machine (in this scenario, I'm dealing with data zones in my real use case, computers is an analogy) can have attributes that are universal to other non-machine type gear (like location can be for a machine and a person). So I do need multiple tables to store their relevant data. I am used to using Oracle sequences, so I am at a bit of a loss here. I am developing an application where spending $$ on Oracle licenses is not a real possibility.

Answer (score 0):

This more a possible approach to the requirement than an answer.

I can create the code if required. It is not a lot of code on top of what is here.

The problem is to maintain tables in an other database, in sync, without doing lots of repeat work.

My suggestion:

In the 'computers' database - have a 'computers_new' table that is inserted to by the 'after insert' trigger and holds the relevant key information. Including a 'unprocessed' column.

I would then run a script at regular intervals or was triggered when the 'computers_new' table changed. It would:

1) transfer the 'unprocessed' details to the 'laptops', 'desktops' tables in the other database.

2) mark the transferred records as processed.

Advantages:

Lots of small chunks of work.
By using transactions it is reliable.

Drawbacks.

Ensuring tables are in sync.